# 3D flip Animation in react native

Tags: android, ios, react-native, animation, 3d

I am researching on how to develop smooth flip transition of 3D Tiles. I have shared the sample UI for mobile app.[UI.UX Tile Design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LLGsj.jpg)

Till now I leanred following methods to do so, but before proceeding I wanted to have better and efficeint suggestions from the professionals;

1. Use color shades (dark and light )for 3d effect illusion and then perform animation according. But while fliping few frames will miss some information.
2. Use [ThreeJs](https://threejs.org/) library to achieve 3d tile and then add rotation effect.

I am still in research phase, may find another efficient solution not compromising frames and performance.

I appreciate your time and consideration. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- First you need to import the necessary libraries & create a functional component for the 3D Tile:

  ```
  import React, {useRef} from 'react';
  import {View, StyleSheet, Animated} from 'react-native';

  const FlipTile = ({children}) => {
   const flipAnim = useRef(new Animated.Value(0)).current;

   const flip = () => {
    Animated.timing(flipAnim, {
     toValue: 1,
     duration: 500,
     useNativeDriver: true,
    }).start();
   };

   const rotateInterpolate = flipAnim.interpolate({
    inputRange: [0, 1],
    outputRange: ['0deg', '180deg'],
   });

   const animatedStyle = {
    transform: [
     {rotateY: rotateInterpolate},
    ],
  };

  return (
   <View style={styles.container}>
     <Animated.View style={[styles.flipCard, animatedStyle]}>
       <View style={styles.flipCardInner}>
         <View style={styles.flipCardFront}>
           {children[0]}
         </View>
         <View style={styles.flipCardBack}>
           {children[1]}
         </View>
       </View>
     </Animated.View>
     <TouchableOpacity style={styles.flipButton} onPress={flip}>
       <Text style={styles.flipText}>Flip</Text>
     </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
   );
  };
  ```
- use this component, simply import it and pass the children as an array containing the front and back faces of the tile.

  ```
  <FlipTile>
  {[
    <View style={styles.tileFront}>
      {/* Your front face content here */}
    </View>,
    <View style={styles.tileBack}>
      {/* Your back face content here */}
    </View>,
  ]}
  </FlipTile>
  ```

Comment: Thanks, your code helped me alot. I was just making it complex. Your simple rotating interpolation logic saved my time. Thanks again